# Using Castle ActiveRecord with Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-activerecord

Has anyone gotten Fluent NHibernate to work with Castle ActiveRecord?

I am particularly interested in Automapping to configure entities for use with the ActiveRecordMediator repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This combo doesn't work yet. When trying to use `ActiveRecordMediator` on a FluentNHibernate-configured entity you'll get an `ActiveRecordException` complaining that you didn't call `ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize()` or you didn't use the `[ActiveRecord]` attribute.

However there [is work being done on this integration](http://mortslikeus.blogspot.com/2009/07/activerecord-fluent-configuration.html).
Wanna help out? I invite you to the [castle dev group](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-devel) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since ActiveRecordMediator can be used with normal nhibernate mapping it should also work with fluent nhibernate.

Comment: how did you do it? AFAIK this just doesn't work, at least not without a lot of hacks.