# How to Combine Castle ActiveRecord entities with normal NHibernate entities?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I am trying to integrate entities defined with ActiveRecord and entities mapped with plain-old .hbm files.

I need to have associations between the two, i.e.:

`ActiveRecordEntity.HbmEntity`

&

`HbmEntity.ActiveRecordEntity`

The only thing I've bumped into that seems at all related is the `ActiveRecordMediator` but it didn't look like it would support this case exactly.

Comment: Which framework do you want "in control"/dominant?

Comment: ActiveRecord. we'd like to move to something that smoothes out the development process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't implemented (yet!). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915454/using-castle-activerecord-with-fluent-nhibernate) for more information, it's the same case.

Comment: @brendanjerwin: here's the placeholder: http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/Config/XmlNhibernateMapping.cs